# The constructor CursorLoader is undefined

Tags: android, sqlite, android-cursoradapter

I am trying to retrieve rows of locations from my SQLiteTable but I ran into a compilation error, the constructor CursorLoader is undefined.

```
@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int arg0,
    Bundle arg1) {

    // Uri to the content provider LocationsContentProvider
    Uri uri = LocationsContentProvider.CONTENT_URI;

    // Fetches all the rows from locations table

    //return new CursorLoader(null);
   //(Context context, Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder)

    /ERROR HERE
    return new CursorLoader(this, null, null, null, null);
}
```

In LocationsContentProvider.java

```
 /** A callback method which is invoked by default content uri */
@Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {

    if(uriMatcher.match(uri)==LOCATIONS){
        return mLocationsDB.getAllLocations();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`CursorLoader` does not have a five-parameter constructor. More importantly, you need to provide the `Uri` pointing to the collection on the `ContentProvider` that you are trying to query. You are welcome to say that the final four parameters are `null`, but add the `Uri` as the second parameter to the constructor.

You may wish to read [the documentation for the six-parameter `CursorLoader` constructor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html#CursorLoader(android.content.Context,%20android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String)) that you will be using.

Also note that the code in your first code snippet will not compile, as you are missing a comma between two of the `null` values.

Answer (score 1):

Cursor Loader constructor get following property :

```
public CursorLoader(Context context, Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection,
            String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
        super(context);
        mObserver = new ForceLoadContentObserver();
        mUri = uri;
        mProjection = projection;
        mSelection = selection;
        mSelectionArgs = selectionArgs;
        mSortOrder = sortOrder;
    }
```

you miss one property. you can add one `null` or define your order and pass to the constructor.

and as CommonsWar said, you must pass your `URI` as a second argument,

Comment: see my edit answer, or see commonsWar answer, you must pass contentProvider Uri to constructor as a second parameter.

Comment: Not sure why but I've forgotten that I was using fragments all along. I just changed "this"to getActivity() and the error is gone.